# How do I find and return all locations of reference value from google worksheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working in Google Sheets. My data looks like this:

[image: Reference Data Table]

The date column may have duplicate values. The Name Columns will have duplicates but not within a row. Same name wont show up twice in a row but may and often will show up more than once in a column or across the columns on different rows. There are hundreds of unique names and hundreds of dates in the data. The data is a living document that will be updated with new row entries (new dates) over time.

I'm trying to return a table of unique names with a list of dates order by recency in another sheet. Basically, I want a table that looks like this:

[image: Target Output Table]

I've tried playing with index, match, and find functions. I keep running into limitations on the reference array (can only search one column at a time). I toyed with trying to save location results from the ctrl+f function. Can't figure out how to do that. I was thinking that if I could save those locations for all instances of a reference name I can convert that into a date based on location of each result. Maybe that is over complicated.

I need to hand off this work to a non-technical audience so I prefer to stick with off the shelf functions rather than custom code.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*Try this in `B2` cell for `John` which outputs the 3 dates as per your test data:*

```js
=unique(torow(arrayformula(if(Reference!D2:G="John",Reference!A2:A,)),1),1)
```

- *Change the tab name in the formula from `Reference` to your local_tabname*

Answer (score 0):

To build your roster column use unique and flatten on the range of the four name columns (assuming no blanks)

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(D2:G)))
```

To build the dates use this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORTN({FILTER(A:A, D:D=I2);FILTER(A:A, E:E=I2);FILTER(A:A, F:F=I2);FILTER(A:A, G:G=I2)}, 3, FALSE))
```

Where A is your column of dates, D/E/F/G are your columns of names. I2 is the roster name reference and the 3 argument in SORTN gives the top 3 results.

The only issue with this is you will get N/A values if each name is not represented in each column. There is way to fix this to remove them using helper columns but a one line solution would be cleaner, but I can't think of it.